# Return only nessesary data in Linq request

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am trying to return only a name of account on get tasks request (because else i will return whole model with userData), but cant figure out how to do it the smartest way, and if it is even possible?

I have 2 models `Account` and `Task`, `Task` have an account bound through *foreign key*.

```
public class Account
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; } 
    public string UserType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class Task
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TaskSubType")]
    public Guid TaskSubTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual TaskSubType TaskSubType { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    public  Guid TaskCreator { get; set; }      
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}  

public IEnumerable<Task> GetTasks()
{
    var result = (from task in db.Tasks select new Task {    
        Account = new Account {Name = task.Account.Name }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return an Entity class (or a "model class") within a projection.

So

```
select new Task
```

will raise an exception, as Task is an Entity.

So you'll have to create a custom class (which will contain the wanted infos from Task and Account in this case) if you want to retrieve only a part of your returned datas.

You can also return an anonymous object, but you'll have some limitations, depending on your scenario.

If you only need one simple property, just select it, and change the return type of your method to the type of that property.

Comment: This is the correct answer in my specific scenario, since i sill want to return a list of tasks, and not a list of strings

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return only names then you don't need to select the entire `Task` object. Just select the required field.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetTasks()
{
    var results = from task in db.Tasks 
                  select task.Account.Name;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your return type to `IEnumerable<string>`

```
public IEnumerable<String> GetTasks()
    return from task in db.Tasks select task.Account.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this will work as you want selecting only `Name` fields of `Account` table

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetTaskAccountNames()
{
    IEnumerable<string> names = 
    (
        from task in db.Tasks 
        select task.Account.Name
    );

    return names;
}
```